# Encountering error while using sockets in socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, sockets, socket.io

I'm learning sockets using socket.io by creating a chat app but I came across some problems. The Node.js server is not logging the data that's supposed to be logged when the socket is connected and when the client joins a room.

This is the code:

Server-

```
import express from 'express'
import cors from 'cors'
import {Server} from 'socket.io'
import dotenv from 'dotenv'
import {createServer} from 'http'

const app = express()
dotenv.config()
const port = process.env.PORT
app.use(cors())
app.use(express.json())

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server Running on Port ${port}`)
})

const server = createServer(app)

const io = new Server(server)

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
    console.log(socket.id)

    socket.on('join_room', (data) => {
        socket.join(data)
        console.log("User joined room: " + data)
    })

    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
        console.log("User Disconnected")
    })
})
```

Client-

```
import './App.css'
import { io } from 'socket.io-client'
import { Fragment, useEffect, useState } from 'react'

var socket
const CONNECTION_PORT = "http://localhost:8000/"

function App() {
  const [logged, setLogged] = useState(false)
  const [room, setRoom] = useState('')
  const [username, setUsername] = useState('')

  useEffect(() => {
    socket = io(CONNECTION_PORT)
  }, [CONNECTION_PORT])

  const connectToRoom = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    setLogged(true)
    socket.emit('join_room', room)
  }

  return(
    <Fragment>
      <div className="App">
        {!logged ?
        (
          <form className="login" onSubmit={connectToRoom}>
            <div className="inputs">
              <input type="text" placeholder="Name" onChange={(e) => setUsername(e.target.value)} />
              <input type="text" placeholder="Room" onChange={(e) => setRoom(e.target.value)} />
            </div>
            <div className="buttons">
              <button className>Enter Chat</button>
            </div>
          </form>
        )
        :
        (
          <h1>You are logged in</h1>
        )}
      </div>
    </Fragment>
  )
}

export default App
```

I'm not sure whether the problem is in the server or client side. I tried running the server with commonjs modules but that didn't work either.

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit -

Found this error in network and console tab: GET http://localhost:8000/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=Nhy6D3- 404 (Not Found)

Did not manage to fix the issue yet

Edit 2 -

Fixed it by adding a proxy in the client package.json

Comment: Do you see any WebSocket activity in the Network tab of dev tools in the browser?

Comment: I found an error there - GET http://localhost:8000/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=Nhy6D3- 404 (Not Found) - Is there something I'm doing wrong in the server?

Answer (score 0):

Could you try removing `CONNECTION_PORT` on the client?

```js
socket = io();
```

That is all that should be necessary to connect to the server socket. See [this example in the socket.io docs](https://socket.io/get-started/chat).